# Why transactions are send to Receiver end at chunks

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, wireshark

I am working in a client server application in which my application is acting as client and we are sending transaction to server. In this communication from my end I am sending transaction of 4443 byes in one stroke, but at server end they receive this transaction details in chunks.

When I checked TCP logs at my end with help of Wireshark I found that from my end also transactions are going to server end in chunks. I have set buffer size of my socket packet to 8092 bytes but still this issue exist, so what can be the reason as I am sending complete data from my application in a single stroke why in network this packets are going in chunks.

Please find Ethereal log file for reference

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "I have set buffer size of my socket packet to 8092 bytes"? Please show your code. Not that it matters much - if you're using TCP but making assumptions about your packets not being split, you're basically misusing TCP, which is a *stream*-based protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on [maximum transfer unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit), which is a property of underlying network. Usually it is 1492 or 1500 bytes for Ethernet networks. Because you use streaming protocol (TCP), you get data chunk as soon as packet arrives, it is application's responsibility to organize it, not the socket's.